# Professor doesn't respond to notice of inability to take a test in his class

Tags: teaching, email, exams

I currently have a concussion that has hindered my ability to do work or study. I went to the doctor and got it diagnosed (got a medical note and all that). I have a midterm tomorrow, and I emailed my professor yesterday regarding my concussion and asked to make it up sometime the following week as I am in no shape to take the test. However, he has not responded (even after I followed up on email). He also posted on my classes discussion board, so I am not sure what to do.

Comment: Have you tried contacting him through the class discussion board or its software, assuming it is something like Canvas, Blackboard, etc. that has a more private means of communication?

Comment: No I have not! Should I do that? I was thinking about doing that, but I did not want to as I felt like I was "pestering" sending him so many messages.

Comment: is there a school policy regarding doctor's notes?

Comment: if you are to miss an exam or final, you need a doctor's note to be able to make it up.

Comment: Isn't there a school secretary?

Comment: What does the instructor's course syllabus say about excused absences from exams?  Does it tell you to go to some university office to be excused rather than contacting the professor directly?

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I can't imagine the entire university having a single secretary. I assume we have different words for this position, can you go into a little bit more detail about who you're asking after?

Comment: @AzorAhai A school secretary... that would be one hell of a job!

Comment: @AzorAhai, in the UK school is occasionally used interchangeably with department, and is never used to describe an entire university. Elsewhere, this position may be a departmental secretary.

Comment: Thanks Emma, indeed! @AzorAhai Of course, I did not talk about a single person, but the face/contact point of the institutional teaching administration, whoever that may be on that particular day and that particular shift.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Still though, you're suggesting they email the professor's department secretary? Or the director of undergraduate studies? It would be unusual for me, in the US, to email the front desk of the dept. about being sick.

Comment: @AzorAhai With no country tag, I used UK terminology. I should think that every country or university has their own way of dealing with student sickness on days of exam. I also would assume that that they are sufficiently alert to replace "secretary" or "reception" in the question with <whoever needs to be contacted to report sickness for the purpose of not losing out in an exam>. This is something students are likely to be informed about early in their studies (even if they typically won't care about until it is needed). TBH I didn't expect such a nontechnical term to create such confusion.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I've never heard of contacting *anyone* besides the prof when you have to miss a test. So I curious if you actually meant contact the reception desk, or if a "school secretary" meant something else wherever they have those. Thanks for clarifying, tho.

Comment: Have you read the syllabus / course instructions? If so, what does it say in there about missing tests for medical reasons?

Answer (score 9):

Professors get a lot of emails every day, and depending on the size of your class, they could be getting even more. I would not after only a day

In any reasonable department, you are fine.  You documented your case by emailing him as soon as you knew you needed to reschedule, and have a doctor's note dated yesterday. If you really want to cover your bases, call his office and leave a message.

In the US (at least), it should not be necessary to go to the exam and ask to be excused*. You don't say how bad your concussion was, but I know that the last time I had a bad one, it would not have been safe for me to travel.

Please rest, you have all the documentation and can figure it out after.

As pointed out in the comments, if your professor is truly a nutcase, you may be able to go to your disabilities services department for help.

---

* Some might wonder if you're healthy enough to do that, why can't you take the exam?

Comment: I think emailing the office for students with disabilities (they deal with temporary things too) or the director of undergraduate studies for the department would have more of an effect than calling the professor. That would also get an official case started in case the professor decides to be difficult.

Comment: I think this is clearly correct. You have given notice. A system that required you to get prior permission in such a situation would be unethical, in my view. Even insane. There are situations, of course, in which an accident occurs that makes it impossible even to send a prior notice and these can be resolved in any sane system after the fact.

Comment: @johanna My point was to create a third time stamped evidence of your request. It's probably not necessary, but could be helpful. Contacting disability services could be helpful but idk if it's necessary just yet.

Comment: @Buffy In fact, that's what I did with the concussion I referenced! I was sitting in the clinic waiting to be seen while I missed a test. It turned out fine.

Comment: Oh. And stop doing the things that give you repeated  bad concussions.

Comment: @Buffy Yeah, I've been trying to avoid getting hit by cars recently

Comment: Do not wait to contact the disabilities office -- they are the people officially tasked with this kind of thing.

Comment: @Elin Meh. One day of no response is not panic mode. I wouldn't stress over contacting them ASAP until the professor makes a problem out of it. This is really a non-issue in any reasonable department and the OP should focus on healing, not navigating bureaucracies. I doubt the resolution would be improved by them contacting now vs. in a couple days.

Comment: First, this student has a serious temporary disability that may end up impacting more than one class. Just because it is one now doesn't mean there won't be others later. He does not have the flu.  Second, legally, accommodations for disabilities are only required if you have registered with the office in advance.   There is no downside to being in touch with them.

Comment: @Elin I'm not sure what the distinction you're making with the flu, since that can also knock you out of multiple classes for a long time. I don't know if you know, but it's recommended you avoid screens directly after a concussion, which would make disabilities services difficult to interact with. Having experienced this situation myself, I'm happy with my recommendations, but you can always add another answer if you think contacting disabilities ASAP is necessary.