# Professor Ignoring Emails RE disagreement over grading

Tags: email, grading

I recently had a concussion. I got everything on paper signed by a doctor, and emailed my teachers immediately. During my medical absence, I missed a quiz. I emailed my teacher regarding making the quiz up, and he said “that’s what the quiz drop is for." However, I had already my quiz drop due to the flu.

I told him I don’t think it’s fair that I have to get a zero for one of the quizzes when both instances were out my control, but he just stopped responding to me. I have followed up twice. What should I do?

Comment: Have the answers and comments on your previous question: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/137906/professor-doesnt-respond-to-notice-of-inability-to-take-a-test-in-his-class not given you sufficient guidance?

Comment: It’s a different issue in my opinion

Comment: Seems like you have not addressed all the suggestions and ways to contact him that were suggested in the previous SE question you posted. Having that evidence is important before you can escalate up the academic grievance pathway. Be gentle on yourself, even mild head injuries can have long term effects that are obvious to others but not yourself, get support, student welfare, etc - https://www.headway.org.uk/about-brain-injury/individuals/effects-of-brain-injury/executive-dysfunction/

Comment: The two questions do seem distinct to me -- the first seemed like a legitimate communication issue, while this one seems like the professor is deliberately not responding to avoid having to discuss this with the OP.

Comment: Does sound like more an escalation policy and how to raise grievance. My comment was whether there was evidence of other ways of proving communication has ceased and being ignored before going through formal channels which was related to the earlier question.

Comment: I do best 4 out of 6 quizzes... And students miss 3 and want a replacement... even though I am being generous with best 4 out of 6... Sometimes you give an inch and they want a yard...

Answer (score 4):

Your professor has probably decided that make-up quizzes are time consuming and not worth it -- students need to learn that sometimes missing an appointment has consequences etc.

I'd recommend checking if the professor is willing to drop 2 quizzes instead of just 1 for the whole class or for anyone who has a doctor's note.

That way you are working with your professor's plan rather than negating it.

Comment: That makes sense. However for both quizzes, I deliberately did not miss them, I physically was not able to show up. That is why I’m confused what to do as I’m not sure what do in this case.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your institution. In UK universities, the process for handling multiple missed assessments due to medical reasons is normally conducted by a designated panel of academics, rather than being at the discretion of an individual course convenor.

In general, there is a limit to how far an academic course will accommodate missed assessments (it would be absurd for somebody to be granted credit if he/she had missed 100% of the assessments, no matter how compelling the reason), and it sounds like you have breached it. In your response to the issue, you need to distinguish between:

- your feelings that the limit is too harsh; and
- the fact that you breached the limit is not your fault.

It sounds like your course convenor has determined that he/she is willing to disregard one assessment, but not more. If the reason for that policy is that he/she considers that disregarding more than one assessment would give an inadequate evaluation of your acumen, then your best recourse may be to ask for the whole course to be disregarded, and to be given an opportunity to start it again from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Check your school's rules regarding missing assignments due to medical conditions. If it says you are excused as long as you present proof , then go to the department of the class you are taking, with the medic recipe and the mail you send the professor plus his response and they will have another professor give you the quiz. If they don't dont then escalate and go to the direction of the school.